# Add a bookmark that is only javascript, not a URL

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I'm thinking that the reason I can't do this is because it might be a huge security hole, but here goes...

I want to have a bookmark on my browser (FF3, preferably) that is only a snippet of javascript code.  It would merely construct a URL based on the current date and then do a window.location = on that URL.

I know that I could make a page and keep it on my local machine and just refer to it that way, but I was just wondering if you could bypass that step and actually have the "location" of the bookmark really just be javascript.  I could have sworn that this was possible years ago, but I can't find anything that tells me either way now.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

What you want is a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) they are easy to create and should work in most major browsers.

Edit: Stack overflow seems not to allow creating bookmarklets in the context of the site, basically you can create a new bookmark and type the following in the location field

```
javascript:window.location='http://www.google.com/search?q='+Date()
```

to get a bookmarklet that searches google for the current date.

Answer (score 26):

It is worthy of note that you can put that in a function wrapper as well.  imranamajeed nicely illustrated that for us... but apparently I'm too new to the site to up his post. :P

so for clarity:

```
javascript:(function(){
  location.href = location.href + "#";
})();
```

(the carriage returns did not affect performance in chrome and IE)

Comment: Yes, wrapping it in a function prevents the return value from messing with the current window.

Answer (score 11):

One minor catch. **IE** can only handle a **508** character URL in this format.  If you save it in IE with a url longer than this, it will truncate without warning and thus fail.

If you need a really complex script, you'll need to use a "hosted" bookmarklet, where you have a short bookmark that injects a script tag into the page, to "call" your hosted bookmarklet.

It isn't as nice/portable, but its the only workaround.

Comment: So the pattern for this is something like:
javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://www.yoursite.com/js/bookmarklet.js';})();

Comment: correct.  You just need to load the script content you want from some other site.

Answer (score 10):

Google Bookmark

```
javascript:(function(){var%20a=window,b=document,c=encodeURIComponent,d=a.open("http://www.google.com/bookmarks/mark?op=edit&output=popup&bkmk="+c(b.location)+"&title="+c(b.title),"bkmk_popup","left="+((a.screenX||a.screenLeft)+10)+",top="+((a.screenY||a.screenTop)+10)+",height=420px,width=550px,resizable=1,alwaysRaised=1");a.setTimeout(function(){d.focus()},300)})();
```

Answer (score 8):

Well, I just created a bookmark in FF3, went back and updated it and added the following test:

```
javascript:alert('Wacky%20test%20yo');
```

Low and behold, after I saved and loaded, I was able to get my alert.

I'm sure you can work up something similar for your needs.