# dynamic bookmarks in Firefox

Tags: date, firefox, dynamic, bookmarks

I have a bookmark in my Firefox like this:

http://foo.bar/index.html?year=2017&month=7&day=21&group=11,21,31&type=something

My question is whether it's possible to dynamically assign year, month and day in such bookmarked URL?
I don't want to change year, month and day every time it has changed. Is there a way to replace it with something like

http://foo.bar/index.html?year=getcurrentyear()&month=getcurrentmonth()

Or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can set a single parameter in the bookmarked url manually from the address bar. You have to bookmark your url, set `short name` for it and replace the part of the url you would like to set dynamically with `%s`, i.e. `https://translate.yandex.ru/?lang=en-ru&text=%s`. After that you may type `url-short-name some-text` in the address bar and open the translation page for `some-text`.
2. A more complex solution is to create a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) like this

   `javascript:(function(){d=new Date();location.href="https://foo.bar/?year="+d.getFullYear()+"&month="+d.getMonth()})();`

   To add this to your bookmarks, you need to bookmark any page and than replace its address with javascript code. I suppose if you are good at Javascript you may come with more elegant code for your bookmark.

You can find more about bookmarklets in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104/add-a-bookmark-that-is-only-javascript-not-a-url).